# How can I find entries that has a date(day and month only which are interval of the next 3 days)

Tags: mysql

Have a field of type Date.
I know there is someway of getting interval of last month like, something like
NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH.

What I need is:

If today is 7.4.15 then I need to select all the entries in a table which has the date field set to 8.4.XX 9.4.XX 10.4.XX - year doesn't matter!

**Edit**: I need also to know how to know use some day interval for searching the next 3 days.

Comment: No it's not read my question please, I have time interval to check

Comment: you can use the interval keyword with a lot of  time periods like DAY, HOUR,YEAR etc. Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add for the whole list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this though it is not very efficient

```
select * from table where 
  date_format(datefield,'%m%d') between 
  date_format(Now() + interval 1 day,'%m%d') and date_format(Now() + interval 3 day,'%m%d');
```

You can probably use %j (day of year 1-366) but I am not sure how it will work for leap years.

Comment: Thanks, don't we have some option to do `Now()+ interval 3 day`

Comment: I tested in on my server and did a few updates a few minutes ago - please check now for the latest version. It should work now with the correct date interval.

Comment: Don't I need to write '%m-%d%' instead?

Comment: it doesn't matter both will work but this way it will be formatted as an integer. If you plan to use it on large table with millions of records you might consider adding a new column with  the month and day only which will allow you to use indexes and will improve the query speed  significantly